# How does 'yield' work in this permutation generator?

Tags: python, generator, permutation, yield

```
def perm_generator(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        yield lst
    else:
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            for perm in perm_generator(lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]):
                yield [lst[i]] + perm
```

This code has been bugging me, since I don't understand how the `yield`s connect to each other. My understanding was that `yield` acts like a `return`, but it stops temporarily until it is called again. How do these `yield`s work?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/1639625

Comment: It sounds more like you do not understand the recursive nature of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help seeing a version that doesn't use generators:

```
def perm_generator(lst):
    res = []
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return [lst]
    else:
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            for perm in perm_generator(lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]):
                res.append([lst[i]] + perm)
    return res

gen = perm_generator([1,2,3])
print gen # prints [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

As you can see - this is not a "find and replace" of "return" with "yield". In the "return" version we needs to accumulate the result while in the "yield" version all that needs to be done is to "yield" the current permutation.