# Storing the result of a for loop in a array

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to save the result of a nested for loop in a list in python. can someone tell me how to do it? 
V is an array containing [1, 2, 3]
while n is the length = 3
and sq is the matrix containing swaps.

i have tried many approaches but whenever i return the result it only gives me one element of the list. 
any help would be appreciated. Thankyou

```
def Permute1(sq,v,n):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if (sq[i,j]==1):
                    temp=v[i]
                    v[i]=v[j]
                    v[j]=temp
                    print(v)



results: 
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: declare an empty list before `for` loops and append the values

Comment: i have tried doing it. but it turns out when i return the list it gives me only the last element in the list. i.e [3,2,1]

Comment: `a=[]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if (sq[i,j]==1):
                temp=v[i]
                v[i]=v[j]
                v[j]=temp
                a.append(v)
    print(a)`

Comment: returns [[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]

Comment: You need to append a **copy** of `v` to `a`. Python will never copy anything (except numerical values) implicitly.

Comment: hi, can you give me an idea for how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the utility of `d = v`here.

To swap two elements in Python, I recommend:

```
v[i], v[j] = v[j], v[i]
```

Declaring an empty list before for loops and append the values (like AkshayNevrekar said) can also be useful, depending on what you need as a result.

Comment: sorry it was a line added by mistake

Comment: Could you give the complete code with the parameters you are passing to the function? Just to see if I can get to your desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979179/how-does-yield-work-in-this-permutation-generator).
You can use this to generate all the permutations and process each one of them & store them in a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Permute1(sq,v,n):
    result=[]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if (sq[i,j]==1):
                temp=v[i]
                v[i]=v[j]
                v[j]=temp
                result += [v]
    print(result)
    return result
```

No tested but may be it can help.